# how to construct a special matrix out of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have two lists as:

```
abs = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
trs = {t1, t2, t3, t4};
```

I like to build the following special matrix:

```
mat = {
   {    0, a2 t1, a3 t1, a4 t1},
   {a1 t2,     0, a3 t2, a4 t2},
   {a1 t3, a2 t3,     0, a4 t3},
   {a1 t4, a2 t4, a3 t4,     0}
   };
```

It is easy to create this matrix $mat$ by several matrix operations. However, I like to obtain $mat$ in a very compact `Mathematica` code. In fact, a `Mathematica` Function such as `F[abs_,trs_]:=` is very much desirable as I will use it in many occasions.

Comment: I assume the `a3 t3` term should be `a3 t4`

Comment: @Mikado: You are perfectly right. The term $a3 t3$ should have been "a3 t4". Thank you for precision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
F[abs_, trs_] := ReplacePart[KroneckerProduct[trs, abs], {k_, k_} -> 0]

F[{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {t1, t2, t3, t4}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \text{a2} \text{t1} & \text{a3} \text{t1} & \text{a4} \text{t1} \\
 \text{a1} \text{t2} & 0 & \text{a3} \text{t2} & \text{a4} \text{t2} \\
 \text{a1} \text{t3} & \text{a2} \text{t3} & 0 & \text{a4} \text{t3} \\
 \text{a1} \text{t4} & \text{a2} \text{t4} & \text{a3} \text{t4} & 0
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: @GravityGuy:  very nice construct...

Comment: Also: `(# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) & [KroneckerProduct[trs, abs]]`

Comment: Yeah, the latter should be faster for large matrices...

Comment: @Henrik: Which one do you refer to when you say "the latter"?

Comment: @Terbernus I meant J.M.'s proposal. In my experience, `ReplacePart` is seldomly a part of an efficient solution.

Comment: @Henrik: You are right. I tried to check both proposals and the former cause a crash in my computer (I lost 20 minutes). Now I will try J.M's proposal with two lists of 10,0000 elements. I hope this time my computer will not crash.

Comment: @Henrik: I checked J.M's proposal with 10,000 elements and my computer again crashed. I think both proposals have different efficiency for lists much less than 10,000 elements. For lists much smaller than 10000 elements, JM's proposal is much better, 60% gain in time compared to the former proposal.

Comment: @Tebernus I almost don't dare to ask: Do you use symbolic list?

Comment: @Henrik: I was just going to let you know that I was using symbolic lists, which caused the crashes, I think. I tried with real number with 10000 elements, and JM's proposal does the job in 2 second (measured with  `Timing`).

Answer (score 8):

Two other alternatives

```
Outer[Times, trs, abs] - DiagonalMatrix[abs*trs]

Transpose[{trs}].{abs} - DiagonalMatrix[abs*trs]
```